# How to refresh page using Serenity Screenplay pattern?

Tags: selenium, page-refresh, ui-testing, serenity-bdd

I need to refresh the page using the Serenity screenplay pattern. I tried to apply

```
user.attemptsTo(Hit.the(Keys.F5).into(element));
```

But it didn't work of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serenity Screenplay does not have a convenience function for refresh, but it should be trivial to roll your own.

```
public class Refresh implements Task {

    public Refresh() { }

    public static Refresh thePage() {

        return Tasks.instrumented(Refresh.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Step("{0} refreshes the browser")
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {

        WebDriver driver = BrowseTheWeb.as(actor).getDriver();
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
}
```